# How to write a `completefunc`/`omnifunc` that tries multiple base values?

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion

I've been trying to write a simple complete function for Vim that tries
multiple values for the `base` argument.

Here is a version that works but which I find unsatisfactory:

```
function! CompleteFunc(findstart, base)
  if a:findstart
    let start = AmbitiousFindStart()
    " -1 to exclude cursor, -1 again to convert column to index
    let fake_base = getline('.')[start:col('.')-2]
    if empty(GetCompletions(fake_base))
      let start = FallbackFindStart()
    endif
    return start
  else
    return GetCompletions(a:base)
  endif
endfunction
set completefunc=CompleteFunc
```

Specifically in my case, `AmbitiousFindStart()` tries to set `start` so as to
consume all non-whitespace characters, but if this fails, I want to use
`FallbackFindStart()`, which only tries to consume word characters.

Here are the problems I see with this approach:

1. Even in the case when `AmbitiousFindStart()` succeeds (i.e. produces matches
   when calling `GetCompletions(fake_base)`), `GetCompletions()` is called
   twice.
2. The `fake_base` approach seems inelegant to me; Vim is the one who is
   suppose to provide me with `base`, rather than me going out of my way to try
   to calculate what `base` would be. Additionally I'm not even sure if my
   `base` calculation is correct (it seems to work in the cases I've tried, but
   there might be problems with e.g. multi-byte characters). I've therefore
   called it the "fake" `base` to distinguish it from the "real" `base` that
   Vim would provide.

My first approach to fix problem (1) was the following, which does not work:

```
function! BadCompleteFunc(findstart, base)
  if a:findstart
    let start = AmbitiousFindStart()
    return start
  else
    let compl_lst = GetCompletions(a:base)
    if empty(compl_lst)
      let fake_base = getline('.')[start:col('.')-2]
      let compl_lst = GetCompletions(fake_base)
    endif
    return compl_lst
  endif
endfunction
```

The problem with this is that Vim uses the `start` value returned from the
first time `BadCompleteFunc()` is called to decide what to replace the
completion with, rather than the string value of `base`.

The second approach I came up with is to use `complete()`, which has problems
of its own:

```
function! Complete()
  let startidx = AmbitiousFindStart()
  let startcol = startidx + 1
  let currcol = col('.')
  let curridx = currcol - 1
  let fake_base = getline('.')[startidx:curridx-1]
  let matches = GetCompletions(fake_base)
  if !empty(matches)
    call complete(startcol, matches)
  else
    let startidx = FallbackFindStart()
    let startcol = startidx + 1
    let fake_base = getline('.')[startidx:curridx-1]
    let matches = GetCompletions(fake_base)
    call complete(startcol, matches)
  endif
  return ''
endfunction
```

The problem here is that this assumes a usage through a custom insert mode
mapping, such as `inoremap <C-X><C-U> <C-R>=Complete()<CR>`, rather than being
able to set `completefunc`.

What is the right way to approach this sort of complete function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'completefunc'` assumes that you can determine the base just by looking at the text before the cursor; then, the call sequence is just fine. In your case, you want a fallback with a different base in case the original base does not yield any completion candidates. For that, you have to call `GetCompletions()` to find out. The only way you could optimize this is storing the result of that first call in a script-local variable, and reusing that when your completion function is invoked the second time around (with `findstart = 0`).

Another way I've solved a similar problem is triggering the fallback only on a second invocation at the same cursor position. So, the user invokes completion, either gets a list of matches or a "no matches" error, and then retriggers the completion. It's both more work, but also offers more control to the user.